# Is there a way to delete parts of a dataframe that are not important for my analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a newbie on Python, and i decide to analyses electoral data from local elections in Brazil.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DULuL.jpg)

Our electoral superior court has pretty decent data on the subject (https://www.tse.jus.br/eleicoes/estatisticas/repositorio-de-dados-eleitorais-1). However, they agregate it by state level, even for municipal elections.

Is there any way to clean all cities but the ones i'm interested? I'm try to conduct some exploratory analisys on city councilors for state capital, Fortaleza. However, the data I have bring information on all 184 state municipalities.

I've been trying to use pandas Groupby(), without sucess till now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a field named `city` or something like that? In pandas you can drop rows based on a mask like this:

```py
new_df = df.drop(df['city'] != 'Fortaleza')
```

Notice that by default it does not drop values inplace, so it will return a new DataFrame, and you'll most likely want to do reset_index to fix the indices in this new DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to the answer given by Thiago, I believe you could condense your dataframe based on a list of cities you wish to look at using the .isin() method:

```
df = df[df['city'].isin(list)]
```

Of course, prior to this you must set list equal to a list of whatever cities you are interested in. Also 'city' being the header for the column containing the city names - I can't tell from the provided picture due to language.